# SignalR with Azure - Forced by Azure.SignalR service by default on release configuration versus debug configuration (.net core 3.1)

Tags: azure, signalr, settings

I have setup an App and deploying using Azure. If I deploy and connect to the Azure SignalR then it is fine, and I can manage with the Azure message limits etc. However, when I try to use the "default" SignalR from my project instead of the Azure service, the release configuration still tries to connect to the Azure one.

In my startup.cs, I am especially trying to NOT use the Azure SignalR.

```
services.AddSignalR();
```

and I have commented out this line that pointed to the Azure one:

```
services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR("Endpoint=https://<myApp>.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=<MyKey>;Version=1.0;");
```

Now when I publish as a Release configuration, Azure online is trying to connect to this host:

> service.signalr.net

Whilst if I publish as a Debug configuration, Azure online is connecting to the host I want:

> .azurewebsites.net

Which is the one I want for now.

Am tryuing to find out which varialbe is "forcing" Azure to use his own Service.SignalR.net in release mode. Could it be some of the variable I can see on the Azure App below? or is it a setting I need to put in the Visual Studio Code?

Thx.

[image]

Comment: So you want on local connect to signalR and on release to Azure Signalr right?

Comment: Following the restrictions and limits on Azure SignalR service, I want to have a choice and sometimes run the normal SignalR service (not the Azure one) on my release environment; Azure added those variables automatically, but i thought that by just declaring AddSignalR instead of AddAzureSignalR in the startup file it would be enough to force Azure to pick up the right SignalR service? apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you can do is something like define the env on startup to use one or another but I can't say what will be the behaviour when you will set your variables on azure.

You should try something like:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<YourHub>("/YourHub");
            });
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseAzureSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<YourHub>("/YourHub");
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thx for this but indeed, even if I use the UseSignalR in the startup file, it still goes and try to use the Azure signalR service. Will try to delete all env variable on Azure side maybe, but its weird behavior...